# home page not found in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following code in .htaccess in wordpress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that when i click to the home url http://www.serversentry.com.au/ page does not redirect to the home page its not found

while other links working properly see

http://www.serversentry.com.au/testimonials/ working properly..

please guide me

Comment: If you remove your permalink settings and make it default, then, your home page is working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
remove IFModule for index.php rewriting and just name your home page as index.php. It should work.